# "sync disabled" and "unfortunately S Planner has stopped"

Tags: sync

I am an old lady with her first smartphone, a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 running Jelly Bean.  Since the last upgrade my email and other apps won't sync and some functions have stopped.  Through 'fiddling' I found an auto sync option which I checked but it made no difference.  I am reluctant to try a factory reset having read about what gets lost in the process.

I don't understand the technical answers to some related questions so could someone please kindly tell me step by simple step how to correct these errors.  I've currently closed all active apps.  I don't have many apps downloaded and don't play games etc but I seem to have accumulated a lot of widgets!  Do I need to do anything with them please?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? "Some functions have stopped": what exactly? Your best bet might be to drop into our chat room when you have time, so we can work together to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, Anne! Some easy questions: Have you already completely turned off the device and powered it up again? If that didn't help, go to *Settings→Apps*, select the "All" tab, and look for the crashing app ("S Planner" here). Open its entry, press the force-close button, then "clear cache". Restart the device again. Let us know if that helped. (not the most elegant variant, but certainly easy to follow I hope). For the sync: what Android version is running on your Note 3 (see *Settings→About*)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: S-Planner and email would not sync. In the sync settings was also an item saying "master sync disabled" but no indication as to how to enable it!

**The fix for me** was to go to the options menu of the phone (when you swipe your finger down from the top of the screen). You should then see a few green and blue symbols (bluetooth/wifi etc.). At the top right there is a gear wheel icon and next to this on the right is another button which when clicked will show all the different icons for your phone settings. Press this and look for the "sync" icon. If it is disabled (blue) then click to enable it.